# How to send several action's parameters together with context to the url Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, fetch-api

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-hrqfyc?file=src%2Fstore%2Findex.js,src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FArrivalDate.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FArrivalPoint.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FDepartureDate.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FDeparturePoint.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FFlight.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FFlightList.vue,src%2Fmain.js

I'm trying How to send several action's parameters together with context to the url, as now I'm getting the 400 error. The selectedPoint and the departurePoint come from child components and are set in its data as variables. So it would look something like:

```js
async getFlights(context, selectedPoint, departurePoint) {
        
      const res = await fetch(
        `http://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/month-matrix?currency=rub&origin=${selectedPoint}&destination=${departurePoint}&show_to_affiliates&token=${context.state.token}`,
      );
      if (res.ok) {
        let result = await res.json();
        context.commit('setFlights', result.data);
      }
      return res.ok;
    },
```

Comment: If you are getting 400 then it means that the endpoint is not found. Also add some more details, like are you getting any console error.

Comment: I've added some info. I'm getting the error as soon as I'm clicking the arrival point input to choose an arrival point

Comment: And I don't get this error when I place only a single parameter after the context in action

Comment: can you share the same then you are not getting the error?

Comment: async getFlights(context, selectedPoint) {
        
  const res = await fetch(
    `http://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/month-matrix?currency=rub&origin=${selectedPoint}&destination=LED&show_to_affiliates&token=${context.state.token}`,
  );
  if (res.ok) {
    let result = await res.json();
    context.commit('setFlights', result.data);
  }
  return res.ok;
}

Answer (score 0):

An action only accepts two params, context and payload.

So here you need to use object when passing multiple params.

```
async getFlights(context, { selectedPoint, departurePoint }) {
    
  const res = await fetch(
    `http://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/month-matrix?currency=rub&origin=${selectedPoint}&destination=${departurePoint}&show_to_affiliates&token=${context.state.token}`,
  );
  if (res.ok) {
    let result = await res.json();
    context.commit('setFlights', result.data);
  }
  return res.ok;
},
```

When calling the action pass the values as an object.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions

Comment: No it unfortunately still gets the 400 error. It still works only with a singe parameter though.